# How do I append two lists of rows into one new row in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have two two csvs with many columns in each.  I am looping through the rows in each and would like to combine the rows as i go into a third csv that has the columns of both. so far this is the only way i can do it:

```
ee = csv.reader(open("ab.csv"), delimiter=",")
cc = csv.reader(open("cd.csv"), delimiter=",")

ofilePosts = open('complete.csv', 'ab')
writerPosts = csv.writer(ofilePosts, delimiter=',')

for e in ee:
    for c in cc:
         complete.writerow(e[0], e[1], e[2]...................
```

This takes along time to manually write out e[x] for the number of rows in x.

How can i just do something like this without getting a run time crash:

```
complete.writerow([e+c])
```

Comment: Try [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: ```getting a run time crash``` : please elaborate.

Comment: Nested loops is the wrong way to go. You want to read a line from each file; concatenate those two lines; write the result to the new file.

Comment: Please include an [mcve]

Comment: Use `csv DictReader/DictWriter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas`, marge them by index so the missing rows from the file with fewer records will be filled by NA.

```
import pandas as pd
ee = pd.read_csv('ab.csv')
cc = pd.read_csv('cd.csv')

merged = pd.concat([ee, cc], axis=1) # merge by index
merged.to_csv('complete.csv') # to dump to a csv
print merged
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from file1 and file2 into a `list` and then append them like so:

```
l =["row1","row2"] #list1
ll = ["row1","row2"] #list2

a = [[l[x],ll[x]] for x in range(len(l))]

print(a) # [['row1', 'row1'], ['row2', 'row2']]
```

This will only work properly if number of rows is same.

Comment: sadly, the two csvs being read from have different numbers of rows. any ideas?

Comment: what should happen to the rows when you are appending it then?

Comment: @majorcoder you can append till the size of the smaller file using that code and then run another loop to add the remaining lines.

Comment: well they should jjust have a column for every of the columns in each of the inputs. so if input csv1 has 5 columns and inputs csv2 has 9 columns then the output csv3 should have 14 columns

Comment: that is what this will do but lets say file1 has 10 rows and file2 has 20 rows, you will have 9 columns but how many columns in the output file?